# « Mettant en jeu » Qu'est ce que ça veut dire?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

> On constate en premier lieu que l'envolée de la croissance depuis le XVIIIe siècle est un phénomène mettant en jeu des taux de croissance annuels relativement modérés,...

Je ne comprends pas. La croissance était grande mais l'envolée n'est que relativement modérée ??

Comment: Ce n'est pas clair ; peut-être pourriez-vous fournir plus de contexte. Le texte à partir du début du paragraphe serait un ajout souhaitable.

Comment: Perhaps consider it like a much more passive version of the literal English translation: “putting into play”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C'est le livre de Thomas Piketty, n'est-ce pas? *Le Capital au XXI<sup>e</sup> siècle*

"l'envolée de la croissance" ne veut pas dire que la croissance était *grande*. Simplement qu'elle a commencé à se développer. Si la stagnation existait auparavant, l'envolée veut dire que la croissance a commencé à se constater à ce moment-là.

> On constate en premier lieu que l’envolée de la croissance depuis le
> XVIIIe siècle est un phénomène mettant en jeu des taux de croissance
> annuels relativement modérés, et en second lieu qu’il s’agit d’un
> phénomène dont les composantes démographiques et économiques ont
> approximativement la même ampleur. D’après les meilleures estimations
> disponibles, le taux de croissance du PIB mondial a été en moyenne de
> 1,6 % par an entre 1700 et 2012, dont 0,8 % par an au titre de la
> croissance de la population, et 0,8 % par an au titre de la croissance
> de la production par habitant.

"un phénomène **mettant en jeu** des taux de croissance annuels relativement modérés" veut dire un phénomène qui **fait agir** les taux de croisssance annuels relativement modérés.

[mettre en jeu Dictionnaire de l'Académie Française](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9J0205)

▪
Mettre en jeu

> Loc. Entrer en jeu, entrer en action ; avoir un rôle, intervenir dans
> une affaire. De nombreux facteurs entrent en jeu dans cette affaire.
> **Mettre une chose en jeu, la faire agir**, l’employer. Il mit en jeu
> toutes les ressources de son imagination. Mettre quelqu’un en jeu, le
> mêler, l’impliquer dans une affaire.

Comment: Merci beaucoup!

Answer (score 1):

Cette phrase est similaire au proverbe très connu :

> [Les petits ruisseaux font les grandes rivières.](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/les_petits_ruisseaux_font_les_grandes_rivi%C3%A8res)

Le sens étant que l'accumulation de taux de croissances annuels modérés conduit, sur une longue durée (plusieurs siècles), à une croissance totale élevée.

Il existe aussi une explication mathématique simple de ce phénomène d'envol, c'est qu'un taux de croissance positif et relativement constant, même faible, étant proportionnel à ce qui est mesuré entraîne sa croissance exponentielle.

*Mettant en jeu* signifie *s'appuyant sur*. Le phénomène d'envolée de la croissance s'est construit sur les effets cumulés des taux annuels successifs.